# Names with different initials from given name in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

Is there a way of making biblatex entries that can handle authors whose first name does not match their initials? For example, the initials of Didi Gregorius are M. J. I want biblatex to produce M.J. Gregorius when giving names with initials, but Didi Gregorius when given full names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the extended syntax to input names. It is described in the biber manual.

```
%test.bib
@article{initials,
author={given=Didi, given-i={M.J.L}, family=Gregorius},
title ={some title},
journal={Journal},
year={2020}
}

@article{initials2,
author={given=Markus, family=Gregorius},
title ={some title},
journal={Journal},
year={2020}
}
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}

\textcite{initials}
\textcite{initials2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]